# ASP.NET Access Specifiers

Tags: c#

1. An application contains multiple projects, is the entire application compiled as one dynamic link library or projects as dynamic link libraries?
2. If dynamic link library is considered an assembly, then keyword `Internal` access would be up to one project.

What I concluded is right?

Comment: Are you looking for ASP.NET related access specifies. or general specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for Question1** : Each project will have its own binaries. If they are Class libraries, then the output would be DLLs, if they are applications then the output will be executables.

Answer (score 0):

No, each project would compile and build its own assembly.  If you mark code as `internal`, code from the other projects would not have access.